# Getting started with gtk.grid with error

Tags: development

i'm getting this error when i try to compile the first gtk.grid in [elementary.io/en/docs/code/getting-started#gtk-grid](https://elementary.io/en/docs/code/getting-started#gtk-grid)

my code;

```
int main(string[] args) {
  Gtk.init (ref args);
  var window = new Gtk.Window ();
  window.title = "project4";

  var grid = new Gtk.Grid ();
  grid.orientation = Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL;
  grid.add (new Gtk.Label ("Label 1"));
  grid.add (new Gtk.Label ("Label 2"));

  this.add (grid);

  window.show_all ();
  Gtk.main ();
  return 0;
}
```

right?

Note: when i change "this.add (grid);" for "window.add (grid);" my compilation works without any error and i run the application with "./"

Is it correct?

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the docs are a bit unclear about this. Your fix is absolutely correct. You want to add your `Gtk.Grid` to a `Gtk.Window` as the window's widget. By using `window.add (grid)` you're doing exactly that, so it's fine that way.

Now let's talk about what the docs are actually trying to say in the paragraph about GtkGrid. Most of the time, you don't want to create a `Gtk.Window` object. You want to create a custom class based on `Gtk.Window` which configures the `Gtk.Window`-specific attributes and adds all your widgets. Take a look at how Pantheon Calculator is doing it: [This is the MainWindow-class](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-apps/pantheon-calculator/trunk/view/head:/src/MainWindow.vala). It's a class which inherits `Gtk.Window` and handles all the logic inside its [constructor](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-apps/pantheon-calculator/trunk/view/head:/src/MainWindow.vala#L51). The custom window is used [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-apps/pantheon-calculator/trunk/view/head:/src/PantheonCalculator.vala) which is a `Granite.Application` created by the `main` function.

`this` is always referring to the current class you're in - so you can only use `this.add (...)` when you're actually *in the `Gtk.Window`* you're using.

You might notice the linked class actually doesn't use `this`. Why? Because you can call a function inside a class and it will look for a function named that way in your class and inherited classes. That's why you can simply use `add (...)` in your window class as well. However, using `this` might be a nice rule because you are always aware of the function's context you just called.